# How to read Binary overlay (*.ovl files) data programmatically

Tags: import

Currenlty, Im dealing with binary Overlay files (*.ovl files) and I needed to read them byte by byte and display the content in a possible way.

I came to know that there can be ASCII and Binary format of Overlay content (*.ovl files) and there are few tools which can read ASCII Ovl files. But, could not get anything on Binary Overlay files.

Could you please anyone point me to possible way of displaying the binary overlay content either by any tool or by programatically (Final aim to program it).

Answer (score 1):

The format is copyrighted by EADS, so you will have little chance to get it read without using their software, or doing something that might be considered as violating their copyright.

See also: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/DE:OVL
(assuming you understand German if you use data from that format).

There is not just one binary format, but already 4 different ones.